# Rails 5.1, add users in group via form and token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, token, grouping

I'm building a Rails app where I have Users, and Groupusers. For both of them there is a controller, model, datas and relation between them.

When you create a new group, you can give a name to this group, the user_id from the one who creates it is saved and a unique token is created as well.

In my user show I loop through all the groups that the current_user created (and will be part of).

I would like the users to be able to join a group by providing the token of this group through a form. Therefore I created a new page called `join.html.erb` I already wrote this for the form :

```
<%= form_for @join, method: :patch do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %>

    <%= f.label :group_user_token %>
    <%= f.text_field :group_user_token, placeholder: "..." %>
    <%= f.submit "Join" %>

<% end %>
```

With this I get the current_user.id to add it in the group.

Problem is that I don't know how to actually add this ID into the group. I had this as a idea :

```
@groupusers.users << @user unless @groupusers.users.include? @user
```

where `@groupuser = Groupuser.find(params[:group_user_token])` and `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`

Problem is that `@groupuser` is not defined in my form as I have to give it. So in my controller I can't go for something like that `@groupuser.update`. Neither in my form, I can't go for `form_for @groupuser`.

I don't know if I'm really clear here, but my question is how to update my group with the token given in the form and add my current_user.

EDIT : I add both of the models

groupuser.rb

```
class Groupuser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_secure_token :group_user_token
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_secure_password
  has_many :spendings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :currencies, through: :spendings
  has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groupusers, dependent: :destroy

    attr_accessor :remember_token



    def User.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                      BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end

    def User.new_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def remember
        self.remember_token = User.new_token
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
    end

    def forget
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
    end

    def authenticated?(remember_token)
        return false if remember_digest.nil?
        BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
    end

end
```

Comment: are you storing uniq token in groups or groupusers?? and post both models too.

Comment: the token is stored in groupuser. I edit the main post for you to see the models

Comment: I think I need a third model  in between no ? I could then use the `has_many through`

Comment: The way I'd do it (and YMMV) is to have a "Memberships" class which `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :group`. Then the join form becomes a form_for @membership and you can use `Group.find_by_slug(your_unique_token)` (or similar)

Comment: Note: you should never have `user_id current_user` in a form because you can always get `current_user` from the login-info and if you have it in your form, then other people can spoof up a different user_id.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Taryn. What if I want to be able to use the spendings, the currencies and the links ? Like users join a group and then "share" the spendings etc... Group.spendings would work if relations are made ? Basically if your in a group you share everything with the group.

Comment: If I use current_user in the views for example is this safe ? Or is there a way to spoof those datas as well ? Example : `user.spendings.all` where user is current_user

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer on my problem. I used a third model that I use as a "bridge" to add my users in groups.

Group.rb

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :members

end
```

Member.rb

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  validates :user_id, :presence => true
  validates :group_id, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:user_id, :group_id]}

end
```

User.rb

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_secure_password

  has_many :spendings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :currencies, through: :spendings
  has_many :links, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
end
```

I made a form where Users can create a new group and I added this on create :

```
def create
    @group = Group.new group_params
    if @group.save
      @user = current_user.id if current_user
      Member.create(group_id: "#{@group.id}", user_id: "#{@user}")
      flash[:success] = "The Group has been created."
      redirect_to group_path(@group)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

So the user is automatically added in the group.

I added a form (and controller of course) for Member.

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @member = Member.new
    end

    def create
        @member = Member.new member_params
        @member.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
        if @member.save
            flash[:success] = "Your Joined the Group."
            redirect_to groups_path
        else
            flash.now[:error] = "Something went wrong. Are you in the group already ?"
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @member = Member.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id], group_id: params[:group_id])
        @member.destroy
        redirect_to root_path, flash: {error: "You left the Group."}
    end

    private

    def member_params
        params.require(:member).permit(:group_id, :user_id)
    end

end
```

With this the user can join a group by entering the group_id. It's not very cool because I would prefer to put my token in place and the user to be able to join the group with this token. That is one of the thing I don't know yet.

Next what I don't know is how in the hell can I remove a User from the group ^^.

I have this in my index :

```
<% user_groups_paginate.each do |group| %>

<tr>
    <td><%= group.name %></td>
    <td><%= group.description %></td>
    <td><%= group.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
    <td><%= group.updated_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to group, class: "btn btn-secondary" do %>
        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        <% end %>
    <%= link_to edit_group_path(group), class: "btn btn-secondary" do %>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        <% end %>

    <%= link_to group, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure that you want to DELETE this group ?" }, class: "btn btn-danger" do %>
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= link_to member_path(group, user_id: user.user_id, group_id: user.group_id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure that you want to LEAVE the group ?" }, class: "btn btn-danger" do %>
        <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
        <% end %>
     </td>
</tr>
```

In my helper :

```
module GroupsHelper

    def user_groups_paginate
        @current_user.groups.all.order('name ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    end

end
```

So with this I can delete a group but how should I manage to add a link (like the others) just to remove the user from the group.

And to finish but that will be for the end... I have other models that I would like to link to the group. For example I have Spending.rb and others. Is it possible once the group is created to group all those datas.

For instance you have a User, this user is adding spendings, links and other stuff for himself. And once grouped, all those datas are shared or grouped with the other users in the same group.

That was long I'm sorry, but I'm on it since 5 hours and I had a lot to tell :)

If anybody can help me for my 2 first problems at least (remove user from group and use token to enter group instead of group_id) would be awesome !

Thanks alot

EDIT : I updated the code. User can now be removed from groups.

Still retrieve the owner of a group by name.
Use the Token instead of the group_id to join a group.
Share datas (between the users of the group) from all my other models when a user join a group.

Comment: Ok I found out how to remove users from the group, I'm working on : How can I retrieve the user.name of the owner of the group. Thing is that I tried that : `@group.members.first.user_id` where `@group = Group.find` and I get the ID so thats cool but I'd like the name ^^. Didn't start the token yet neither the relation with the other models.

Comment: Maybe I have to add some stuff in my DB like `belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"` in group.rb and something like : `has_one :owned_group, foreign_key: "owner_id", class_name: "Group"` in user.rb. Any opinion about that one ? Even tho I don't know how to retrieve the name with this...